# Implement change capture

Tags: shell-script

I have two directories, namely "before" and "after" , each of which has it's sub-directories and files.I want to display all the INCREMENTAL changes amongst these two folders from depth 1 level.

```
What is I mean is to compare the outputs of the following  
commands and display the differences.

1. find before/ -mindepth 1
2. find after/ -mindepth 1

After cimparison I want to display the following:
a."A" before files/folders present ONLY in the after/ 
     hierarchy(these will be deemed as newly added 
      components)
b. "D" before files/folders present ONLY in the before/ 
     hierarchy(these will be deemed as deleted
      components)
c. "M" before files/folders present in BOTH before/  and 
     after/  hierarchies(these will be deemed as modified
      components)
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem at hand? Have you tried using `diff` on the pre/post output of `find`? That could get you started.

Comment: diff -daU 0 before/  after/.                                           But I cannot format the A/D/M indicators

Comment: Not what I meant :). You could do something like: `find before -mindepth 1 > state-before`, `find after -mindepth 1 > state-after` and then `diff state-before state-after`. It's also possible to use special syntax for that (`diff <(find ...) <(find ...)` IIRC, but I'm not sure about portability).

Comment: Not sure about the A/D/M stuff, but "diff -r --brief before after" should give you output that you can then reformat as you see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps even better than `diff`-ing the output would be this:

```
#!/bin/sh -eux

find before -mindepth 1 -printf "%p D\n" | cut -d/ -f2- | sort > files-before
find after -mindepth 1 -printf "%p A\n" | cut -d/ -f2- | sort > files-after
join -a2 -a1 files-before files-after | sed 's/D A$/M'
```

where:

- we search in `before` and `after` for all files,
- omit the `before` and `after` directories themselves (`-mindepth 1`),
- append `D` to files found under `before` and `A` to files under `after`,
- remove the first component of the path from all found files (the `cut`),
- sort the results and store in two separate files.

The last command:

- pairs lines which speak about the same file (see `man join`), so that each file (relative to the search dir, because we removed that) appears exactly once, with a `D` if the file was in `before` or `A` if it was in `after` or `D A` if it was in both),
- we include file names which only appear in one of the input files (the `-a1 -a2`),
- finally, if a file has both the `D` and the `A` flag, we change it to `M` as requested.

Comment: Thanks David. I will give this a try and let you know the results.